# FormulaLocal VBA

Tags: vba, formula

I have a problem with start a program. at the end of I have error.
Can I please help me?

```
Sub EnterAFormula()

Dim Myformula As String

Myformula = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a formula", Type:=0)

Myformula = Range("G2").FormulaLocal
```

Comment: What kind of error? What is the content of range "G2"?

Comment: Maybe you want to write `Myformula` into cell G2? In that case, the last line is wrong, you should try: `Range("G2").FormulaLocal = Myformula`